# Boto3 Error: botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials via shell script

Tags: boto3, boto

When I run from CLI(terminal) it works, it finds the credentials via sso and passes on
EX:

```
2022-06-18 07:38:36,421 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role
2022-06-18 07:38:36,421 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role-with-web-identity
2022-06-18 07:38:36,421 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: sso
2022-06-18 07:38:36,422 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/2.7.8/dist/awscli/botocore/data/endpoints.json
2022-06-18 07:38:36,432 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x7fb797891040>
2022-06-18 07:38:36,433 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event creating-client-class.ecr: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7fb797909820>
```

When I run the same command via a shell script it doesn't find the credentials:

```
2022-06-18 07:38:53,667 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.get-login-password: calling handler <function add_waiters at 0x7fa1820bf9d8>
2022-06-18 07:38:53,667 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role
2022-06-18 07:38:53,667 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role-with-web-identity
2022-06-18 07:38:53,668 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: shared-credentials-file
2022-06-18 07:38:53,668 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: custom-process
2022-06-18 07:38:53,668 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: config-file
2022-06-18 07:38:53,668 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: ec2-credentials-file
2022-06-18 07:38:53,668 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: boto-config
2022-06-18 07:38:53,668 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: container-role
2022-06-18 07:38:53,668 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: iam-role
```

This is the command:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region xxx --profile xxx | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin xxxxxx.amazonaws.com
```

Am I missing a configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue with the bellow commands:

```
python3 -m pip install --user aws-export-credentials
```

and

```
pip3 install --upgrade awscli
```

This also helped me a lot:
https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4982